# Why is there a drop call after structure destructuring?

Tags: rust, destructuring

I am wrapping a C API. To simplify for this question, I'm using `NonNull::dangling` instead.

```
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct Foo(NonNull<i32>);

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo::drop: {:?}", self.0);
    }
}

struct Moo(NonNull<i32>);
//impl Drop for Moo exists, but not important for question

fn f1() -> Result<Foo, String> {
    Ok(Foo(unsafe { NonNull::dangling() }))
}

fn f2() -> Result<Moo, String> {
    f1().map(|Foo(x)| Moo(x))//1
}

fn main() {
    f2();
}
```

At point (1), I unpack/destructure `Foo`. I expect that after that, `Foo::drop` should not be called, but for some reason `Foo::drop` is printed.

Am I wrong that destructuring (`let Struct1 { field1, field2, .. } = struct1;`) should prevent the call of `Struct1::drop`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace `NonNull` with a struct which does not implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), the behavior is more clear:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NoCopy;

struct Foo(NoCopy);

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo::drop: {:?}", self.0);
    }
}

struct Moo(NoCopy);
//impl Drop for Moo exists, but not important for question

fn f1() -> Result<Foo, String> {
    Ok(Foo(NoCopy))
}

fn f2() -> Result<Moo, String> {
    f1().map(|Foo(x)| Moo(x))//1
}

fn main() {
    f2();
}
```

This results in this error:

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `Foo`, which implements the `Drop` trait
  --> src/main.rs:20:15
   |
20 |     f1().map(|Foo(x)| Moo(x))//1
   |               ^^^^-^
   |               |   |
   |               |   data moved here
   |               cannot move out of here
   |
note: move occurs because `x` has type `NoCopy`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  --> src/main.rs:20:19
   |
20 |     f1().map(|Foo(x)| Moo(x))//1
   |
```

Therefore, in (1) you copy the `NonNull` out of `Foo` and `Foo` gets dropped.

Comment: Btw. you cannot move out of `Foo` (`f1().map(|x| Moo(x.0))`) as `Foo` implements `Drop`